# На какой уровень домена распространяется сертификат

Tags: ssl, домен, openssl, поддомены, сертификат

На какой уровень домена сайта распространяется подписанный сертификат центром сертификации (например Comodo), если в сертификате указано 2 DNS имени: mysite.ru и *.mysite.ru.

Answer (score 0):

Сертификат защищает все поддомены, вида *.site.ru. Т.е. он защищает: www.site.ru, shop.site.ru, mail.site.ru, forum.site.ru и т.д. Но не защищает: my.shop.site.ru.

Такой тип сертификата называется «Wildcard».